# Django lettuce, loading fixtures

Tags: django, lettuce

I am trying to insert data from my fixtures into the test database so that I can test my views however, the fixtures do not load in Django lettuce.

My steps file

```
@step(u'Given I have the following movies')
def given_i_have_the_following_movies(step):
    for movie in step.hashes:
        movies = Movie(**movie)
        movies.save()


@step(u'then I should see my movies listed on the home page')
def then_i_should_see_my_movies_listed_on_the_home_page(step):
    for movie in step.hashes:
        assert movie['title'] in world.browser.page_source
        assert movie['actors'] in world.browser.page_source
        assert movie['running_time'] in world.browser.page_source
        assert movie['showtime'] in world.browser.page_source
```

My fixtures file

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "ticketing.movie", "fields": {"title": "Robocop(2014)", "actors": "Joel Kinnaman, Gary Oldman, Michael Keaton", "running_time":"105 mins", "showtime":"9.30pm"}},
```

How can I get the fixtures file to load once harvest runs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`@before.each_scenario`](http://lettuce.it/reference/terrain.html#lettuce-before-each-scenario) as in the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lettuce-users/_KYSkqv78KY).

You should also look at [`@after.harvest`](http://lettuce.it/reference/terrain.html#lettuce-after-harvest).